# How run a python script one line by one line (pause after every line)?

Tags: python, python-module

I have seen someone using such a module in a video course or something. However, I googled and found nothing.

As I can remember, a module is imported at the beginning of the script. When running, the script is paused after every line, and the result is shown. This module is great for presentation.

Comment: You can use an IDE such as PyCharm, Visual Studio, etc. Step through your code with a debugger. These IDEs have very powerful tools, it would be useful for you to learn how to use one or more of them. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) for which IDEs have which features.

Comment: Use pdb https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html or any Python IDE with Debugger (PyDev, Pycharm,…).

Comment: I know pdb and I believe its not what I need. pdb is designed for debugging while the module I mentioned is for presentation.

Comment: Finally I found it in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woKYyhLCcnU . What I seen is sliderepl.py . I made a mistake as it's not a module to be imported. The last update of sliderepl is 3 years ago and it does not support Python 3.  I will use pdb/ipdb instead as they are much more powerful. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There's a problem that pdb/ipdb will hang the GUI event loop. I want to run the script line by line to do a presentation, and the GUI should be running when paused. Finally I found what I want could be achieved by IPython Notebook. The magic command %gui is necessary so that the GUI event loop is not hang after running each cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ipdb`.

You just import it and then call the trace:

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

To go step by step you press `n`, or `c` to continue until the next break point (which you can set up in the script or in the ipdb console yourself).

See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb for more info.